# How to pivot tables view/results from row to columns

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have e-mail aliases tables that looks like this:

```
+---------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| address                         | name                     | accesspolicy            | domain      | created             | modified            | expired             | active |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| user1alias1@domain.com          | User1 Frist_LastName     | User1_email@domain.com  | domain.com  | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |
| user1alias2@domain.com          | User1 Frist_LastName     | User1_email@domain.com  | domain.com  | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |
| user1alias3@domain.com          | User1 Frist_LastName     | User1_email@domain.com  | domain.com  | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |
| user1alias4@domain.com          | User1 Frist_LastName     | User1_email@domain.com  | domain.com  | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |

| user2alias1@domain.com          | User2 Frist_LastName     | User2_email@domain.com  | domain.com  | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |
| user2alias2@domain.com          | User2 Frist_LastName     | User2_email@domain.com  | domain.com  | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |
| user2alias3@domain.com          | User2 Frist_LastName     | User2_email@domain.com  | domain.com  | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |

| user1alias1@domain2.com         | User1 Frist_LastName     | User1_email@domain2.com | domain2.com | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |
| user1alias2@domain2.com         | User1 Frist_LastName     | User1_email@domain2.com | domain2.com | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |
| user1alias3@domain2.com         | User1 Frist_LastName     | User1_email@domain2.com | domain2.com | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |

| user2alias1@domain2.com         | User2 Frist_LastName     | User2_email@domain2.com | domain2.com | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |
| user2alias2@domain2.com         | User2 Frist_LastName     | User2_email@domain2.com | domain2.com | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |
| user2alias3@domain2.com         | User2 Frist_LastName     | User2_email@domain2.com | domain2.com | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |
| user2alias4@domain2.com         | User2 Frist_LastName     | User2_email@domain2.com | domain2.com | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 1970-01-01 01:01:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |      1 |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

I'm looking how can create (select / create view) result outcome that looks something like this:

```
+---------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| accesspolicy                    | name                     | domain       | alias1                  | alias2                  | alias3                  | alias4                  | active |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| User1_email@domain.com          | User1 Frist_LastName     | domain.com   | user1alias1@domain.com  | user1alias2@domain.com  | user1alias3@domain.com  | user1alias4@domain.com  |      1 |
| User1_email@domain2.com         | User1 Frist_LastName     | domain2.com  | user1alias1@domain2.com | user1alias2@domain2.com | user1alias3@domain2.com | NULL                    |      1 |
| User2_email@domain.com          | User2 Frist_LastName     | domain.com   | user2alias1@domain.com  | user2alias2@domain.com  | user2alias3@domain.com  | NULL                    |      1 |
| User2_email@domain2.com         | User2 Frist_LastName     | domain2.com  | user2alias1@domain2.com | user2alias2@domain2.com | user2alias3@domain2.com | user2alias4@domain2.com |      1 |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

Comment: It's MySQL 5.7.24 server. and I need to create a view table for e-mail server (sogo). In all the cases active=1 if not record is deleted but for table view the column is not required. In the view tables required columns are (accesspolicy, name, domain, alias 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-*)

Comment: As I understand the maximum count of aliases for single accesspolicy is not limited. Is it?

Comment: no it's not, but lets assume that I limit to 10.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the next solution. You use the query:

```
SELECT accesspolicy, name, domain, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT address) all_aliases
FROM source_table
GROUP BY accesspolicy, name, domain
```

Additionally you may add ORDER BY clause into GROUP_CONCAT if needed.

Its output looks like:

```
+--------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| accesspolicy             | name                  | domain       | all_aliases                                                                                     |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| User1_email@domain.com   | User1 Frist_LastName  | domain.com   | user1alias1@domain.com,user1alias2@domain.com,user1alias3@domain.com,user1alias4@domain.com     |
| User1_email@domain2.com  | User1 Frist_LastName  | domain2.com  | user1alias1@domain2.com,user1alias2@domain2.com,user1alias3@domain2.com                         |
| User2_email@domain.com   | User2 Frist_LastName  | domain.com   | user2alias1@domain.com,user2alias2@domain.com,user2alias3@domain.com                            |
| User2_email@domain2.com  | User2 Frist_LastName  | domain2.com  | user2alias1@domain2.com,user2alias2@domain2.com,user2alias3@domain2.com,user2alias4@domain2.com |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then, on the client side, you may (if needed) split the `all_aliases` column to separate columns. For to know the number of columns which you need to create in output grid you may previously ask it with the query:

```
SELECT MAX(cnt) columns_count
FROM ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT address)
       FROM source_table
       GROUP BY accesspolicy, name, domain ) x
```

If a combination `(accesspolicy, name, domain, address)` is unique (checked by unique index) you may remove DISTINCTs.